# pivottable.js unselect derivedattribute dropdown by default

Tags: jquery, pivottable.js

I am adding derived attribute to pivottable.js using code as follow,

```
 derivedAttributes: {
                    "date": derivers.dateFormat("Date", "%d/%m/%y-%w"),
                    "Month": $.pivotUtilities.derivers.dateFormat("DateTime", "%n",true),
                    "Year":  $.pivotUtilities.derivers.dateFormat("DateTime", "%y",true),

},
```

and this code adds attribute to pivotable.js as shown in below image

[image]

As you can see in above image, there are 4 items(215,2016,2017,2018) in year drop-down, and all of them are checked. But **I do not want all of them need to be checked** by default, when pivotable is rendered or loaded , instead I want at least one or none selected in the drop-down.

Kindly let me know how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exclusions` parameter to uncheck certain options by default.

Comment: After adding exclusions:[2018] parameter,  I am getting TypeError: o is not a function   at o (pivot.coffee:334)

Comment: Yes, that's not the format of the `exclusions` parameters... it needs to be an object of arrays, not an array. Try `exclusions: {"Year": [2018]}` instead.

Comment: same is error is coming TypeError: o is not a function
    at o (pivot.coffee:334)
    at Function.e.forEachRecord (pivot.coffee:347)
    at r.fn.init.t.fn.pivotUI (pivot.coffee:689)

Comment: OK, please file a Github Issue at https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/new and I'll try to give you a hand.